# Installshield 11 showing bad system call(core dumped) error while installing on solaris 11 x64

Tags: solaris

I am getting bad system call(core dumped) error while installing installshield on Solaris 11 x64. How should I troubleshoot this or any breakthroughs for getting more info on this inside Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

You should examine what  "file" on the installshield executable returns, as well as `ldd` says.

If the binary is (partially) statically linked, it may not work as only
the interfaces defined in the dynamically linked libc are public.

If a binary is statically linked with libc, it may fail later in newer release.
In Solaris 11, we removed a number of the old system calls.